# Suppress all output from Python/unittest

Tags: python, shell, unit-testing

I'm trying to suppress **ALL** terminal output from python's unittest and wish to give only custom feedback based on if the test passed or failed. Nothing I've found online seems to work. My use-case is to provide feedback/hints to new students learning Python.

I'm calling unittest with my shell script (I've tried several variations of "dev/null"):

```
if python -m unittest discover -s test; then
    echo "<div class='pass'>pass</div>"
else
    echo "<div class='fail'>fail</div>"
fi >>/dev/null
```

Below is my python unittest file:

```
import unittest
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/module')
import myFile

sys.stdout = os.devnull //tried this but didn't work
sys.stderr = os.devnull //tried this but didn't work

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_add(self):
    result = calc.add(10, 5)
    self.assertEqual(result, 15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

The echo in my shell script does, in fact, run based on if the test passes or fails, but above it is all the terminal output which I don't want. (The output is in an interactive IDE when I run it)

Addendum: I wasn't able to find any unittest optional parameters either to suppress all the output.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement your own `TestRunner`, and use it instead of [`TextTestRunner`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner) which [`unittest.main()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) uses by default.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (in addition to writing your own TestRunner as it was suggested by Daniel Pryden) is to simply wrap the call to the test executable from the command line and filter out (for example with `grep`, `awk`, `perl` or another `Python` script) only the part of the output you want to become visible.